# Why can't I spend my destiny points?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

I've got a couple thousand destiny points, but the Use Destiny button is grayed out; why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Looks](http://www.lotro.com/free.php) like you have to have a VIP account to spend Destiny Points. F2P and Premium can earn but can't spend.