# What are destiny points in LOTRO?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

I have a free Lord of the Rings Online account.

What are destiny points?
How do you earn these points?
What can you do with them?

Comment: You might also be interested in this question http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7252/why-cant-i-spend-my-destiny-points

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LOTRO Destiny Points (DP) can be earned by playing as Monster or by gaining levels after level 10 (200 destiny points each level).

Destiny Points can be spent in two ways:

- In Monster Play (buy skill, traits, play as Troll, etc.)
- Buying Player Perks

The are many useful perks that can help your character leveling faster, increase movement speed, armor and so on.

I suggest you to look at [LOTRO Wiki](http://lotro-wiki.com/index.php/Destiny_Points) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

You have a free account, so I'm afraid the answer is: You can't do anything with them. You need a subscription to use them. (I.e., VIP accounts only)

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you log into monster play, free/premium players can use them to purchase skills or corruptions.